# gotta be a better way of doing this SQL WHERE/IN s

Tags: sql, oracle

i have to test my Select statement returns against a Where/In clause that is completely unwieldy.  I'm sure it could be worse with tens of thousands of numbers to check against, but this looks bad to me, despite the fact that it works.

```
Where p.description Like '%UbD%'
  Or pa.text Like '%UbD%'
And p.state_code_id IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','65')
```

how can i have the statement check something like '1-50','65' instead?  is it possible?  i'm using oracle.

Comment: try `(p.state_code BETWEEN '1' AND '50' OR p.state_code == '65')`

Comment: while the in isn't ideal, I think you'd take more of a hit on performance from the wildcard searches unable to use indexes.  You may be able to add an inner join which would limit the data but you'd first somehow have to get the set 1-50 and 65  which would be dependent on other data...

Comment: sql should use =, not == (just a note - I'm sure you know that)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Where p.description Like '%UbD%'
  Or pa.text Like '%UbD%'
  And ((p.state_code_id BETWEEN 1 AND 50) OR p.state_code_id = 65)
```

Comment: I'm almost sure you can safely use `AND p.state_code_id BETWEEN 1 AND 65`

Comment: @tftd But that would include the values between 51 and 64, which the OP does not want

Comment: Ahh... I missed that part in the question. :)

Comment: This will work if all values for p.STATE_CODE are numeric.  If there are any alphabetic values in p.STATE_CODE it will fail due to a numeric conversion error.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
 AND ((p.state_code BETWEEN 1 AND 50) OR p.state_code = 65)
```

Comment: who in the world is running around downmarking correct answers less than a second after posted?

Comment: All of the downvotes (some of which have been subsequently retracted) occurred on answers missing parentheses or that were incomplete.

Comment: I see that now - million times more helpful to everyone to explain yourself

Comment: Offtopic siderant: It always annoys me when people downvote without helping the OP or answerer know what's wrong, to help them improve their post.

Comment: @jmadsen - some people simply don't have enough to do.

Comment: no problem with down-voting a bad answer - mine would have caused OP a headache if he'd used it literally. Just more helpful to remember we're all here to help & learn, not rank :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not changing the query, but makes it more maintainable. Put the data into a table and use a subquery...

```
Where p.description Like '%UbD%'
  Or pa.text Like '%UbD%'
And p.state_code_id IN (SELECT ID FROM States)
```

Comment: +1, my thoughts exactly, glad someone said it (or similarly, join to the ref table)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming positive state codes and no 0, you could use:

```
AND (p.state_code_id <= 50
     OR p.state_code_id = 65)
```

Comment: Assumes the field does not have negative numbers or 0.

Comment: It's not entirely odd to me, I've seen code that uses negative numbers as states for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If your codes are always the same, do what the other guys said. If they are **different**, then **create a temporary table**. Insert all your desired values into that new (temporary table) and do a **join on both**.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM p, temp 
WHERE p.description Like '%xyz%' AND p.state_code == temp.code
```

Comment: Well that depends if the codes change or not. IF they do, then this is much easier than creating a gigantic query. You can have the temporary table always there, just empty.

Comment: fair enough - for dynamic would work, though in the past I've just created a (php for me) function to split it out into statement. yours was actually my first thoght

Comment: I'v also done statements in the past. And then I moved to Windows Server from ubuntu and suddenly MySQL just died on my gigantic query. That's how I've realized that something wasn't right with my technique :P